# Elementary proof that centre of finite $p$ group is not trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove that the centre of finite $p$ group is not trivial.

I have found on many links proofs of this property, but all of them use the "Class Equation". I would like to know if there is a proof which doesn't use class equation or cosets, but only simpler properties of elements in groups.

For example, the order of an element, Lagrange or Cauchy theorems

Comment: Not sure whether there is a general easy proof. In the case of order $p^2$, there is one.

Comment: The duplicate avoids the class equation.